# Subtract data.table from another data.table when unique row ID and column names match

Tags: r, data.table, subtraction

I would like to subtract `dt2` from `dt1` to generate the output shown in `dt3`. I would then like to subset `dt3` so only rows that contain a negative value remain (like `dt4`).

```
dt1 <- data.table(
  UID=c("A001","A002","A003","B001","B002","B003","C001","C002","C003"),
  Var1=c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500,600,700,800,900),
  Var2=c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000,6000,7000,8000,9000),
  Var3=c(10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000,60000,70000,80000,90000),
  Var4=c(15000, 25000, 35000, 45000, 55000,65000,75000,85000,95000))

dt2 <- data.table(
  UID=c("A001","A003","B001","B003","C001","C003"),
  Var1=c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50,950),
  Var2=c(100, 2500, 300, 400, 500,600),
  Var3=c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000,6000))

dt3 <- data.table(
  UID=c("A001","A002","A003","B001","B002","B003","C001","C002","C003"),
  Var1=c(90, 200, 280, 370, 500,560,650,800,-50),
  Var2=c(900, 2000, -500, 3700, 5000,5600,6500,8000,8400),
  Var3=c(9000, 20000, 28000, 37000, 50000,56000,65000,80000,84000),
  Var4=c(15000, 25000, 35000, 45000, 55000,65000,75000,85000,95000))

dt4 <- dt3[c(3,9),]
```

Comment: i think you have a typo for Var2 when UID=A003. 3000 - 2500 = 500 not -500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible approach:

```
DT <- copy(dt1)

#subtracting
cols <- setdiff(names(dt2), "UID")
DT[dt2, on=.(UID), (cols) := .SD - mget(paste0("i.", cols)), .SDcols=cols]

#subsetting
DT[Reduce(`|`, lapply(DT, `<`, 0))]
```

output:

```
    UID Var1 Var2  Var3  Var4
1: C003  -50 8400 84000 95000
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier to convert it to a long format first.

```
library(data.table)

dt1 <- data.table(
  UID=c("A001","A002","A003","B001","B002","B003","C001","C002","C003"),
  Var1=c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500,600,700,800,900),
  Var2=c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000,6000,7000,8000,9000),
  Var3=c(10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000,60000,70000,80000,90000),
  Var4=c(15000, 25000, 35000, 45000, 55000,65000,75000,85000,95000))

dt2 <- data.table(
  UID=c("A001","A003","B001","B003","C001","C003"),
  Var1=c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50,950),
  Var2=c(100, 2500, 300, 400, 500,600),
  Var3=c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000,6000))

dt2 <- 
melt(dt2, "UID")[melt(dt1, "UID"), on = c("UID", "variable")][
  , sum(i.value, -1 * value, na.rm = TRUE), .(UID, variable)]

dt3 <- dcast(dt2, UID ~  variable)

dt4 <- dcast(dt2[UID %in% dt2[V1 < 0, UID]], UID ~  variable)
```